# Bar button item event not activate in ios 6 or late

Tags: uibarbuttonitem

I tried this code:
custom barbuttonitem:

```
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image title:(NSString*)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame= CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
button.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
button.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.5];
button.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
[button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIView *view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height) ];
[view addSubview:button];
self = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
return self;
```

}

and used it:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_account_icon.png"] title:@"" target:self action:@selector(buttonClick:)];
```

But in ios 6 event not activate, ios 5 run nomal, please help me !!!!

Answer (score 0):

`UIBarButtonItem`s with a `customView` set will not fire actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image title:(NSString*)title target:(id)target action:(SEL)action 
{
    //create whatever custom views you need

    UIView *view =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height) ];

    UITapGestureRecognizer * gestureRec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: target action: action];
    [view addGestureRecognizer: gestureRec];

    //add your custom subviews to the view

    self = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
    return self;
}
```

Adding gesture recognizer to the subview of the UIBarButtonItem worked for me, even if UIBarButtonItem is initialized with the custom view.
Good luck!